# Angular 6 - "Service workers are disabled or not supported" error

Tags: angular, push-notification

I want to push notification subscription with `web-push` module and `angular service worker`. I've followed instructions from these links: [Angular Push Notifications: a Complete Step-by-Step Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/) and [Push Notifications with Angular & Express](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-push-notifications) yet the notification prompt was not showing up as it should. I've checked the `swPush` object and found out that it was not enabled, and I don't know why even I've followed `angular/pwa` installation instructions exactly as those links said. Hope someone here can help. Thanks a lot!

I run the application with my own `Nodejs` server, not with `http-server` module.

Here is my push subcription code:

```
readonly VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY =
'BIfDkegCvhzctX06rYvwQImhbfAymWYE3wtcog9E4Zj7LOgX6TQFS6fZSqLCt01zBZtc1-jSwpZrZEmTQ2i95V8'; // key generated with web-push

 constructor(
   private user: UserService,
   private httpClient: HttpClient,
   private router: Router,
   private auth: AuthService,
   private swPush: SwPush
 ) {
     this.swPush.requestSubscription({
       serverPublicKey: this.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
     })
     .then(subcription => {
       console.log('Send ' + subcription + ' to server');
     })
     .catch(console.error);
}
```

Error returned:

> Error: Service workers are disabled or not supported by this browser
>       at SwPush.push../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/fesm5/service-worker.js.SwPush.requestSubscription (service-worker.js:146)
>       at new DashboardComponent (dashboard.component.ts:40)
>       at createClass (core.js:9311)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:9186)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:10406)
>       at createRootView (core.js:10320)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:10838)
>       at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:8666)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:3315)

Expected result:

[image: result]

Comment: Maybe your browser did not support web-push? Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045748/angular-service-worker-on-the-browsers-that-do-not-support-it

Comment: I ran it on chrome. But I figured out that it is because I ran the app with `ng serve` and the service worker doesn't work with `ng serve`. I ran the app again using `http-server` and it worked fine.

Comment: Ok Yes, thats right

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error was caused due to the reason that service workers don't work with `ng serve`. Run with `http-server` then it works fine.
As in [Angular service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) said:

> Because ng serve does not work with service workers, you must use a separate HTTP server to test your project locally. You can use any HTTP server

Comment: .. except on localhost

Comment: is it possible to disable the error on localhost with ng serve?

Comment: i ran it with http-server but still get the error

Answer (score 15):

Just set the service worker to work in dev environment also in 'AppModule'

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production})
```

To

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: true})
```

Comment: For those like me stumbling across this running `ng serve` (which is *not* actually the scope of the question, I know), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905172/how-to-run-service-worker-locally-with-angular#answer-59785846 for a workaround.