# Cannot use service worker on localhost with Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, service-worker

I am making a Pwa with ionic

I wish to debug the service worker without running the command "ionic build --prod" each time i make a change !
So i wish to be able to load the service worker on localhost but i have this error :

```
Error TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8100/') with script ('http://localhost:8100/service-worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

The service-worker.js file is located in the "src" folder of my ionic app project

A possible answer to my problem here [How to run service worker locally with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905172/how-to-run-service-worker-locally-with-angular)

Comment: Pretty much you answered yourself. You can't run the service worker locally without having to build the project and then use a library to run a local https server. Please read https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/

Comment: Thank you, I wish to debug my webapp before to compile and build it. I think about serving src folder from an external server than localhost because localhost is not https. Another possible answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492354/how-to-allow-access-outside-localhost

Comment: I wish to run it from an external server hosting so i won't have to rebuild the app each time i make a change !

Comment: The solution i  found is ngrok service it is serving from outside localhost

Comment: You could host using firebase, the is a good tutorial on Ionic docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/pwa#deploying