# How to run service worker along with angular ng-serve locally

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

[image: 1]

Having issues in deployment for service workers.

showing error in status #961 trying to install

Trying to run angular ng-serve on port 4200, want to run angular and service worker on

```
ng-serve
```

````
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>mPokket| Admin</title>
  <base href="/v2">
  <!-- <base href="./"> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>:root { --recon-theme-color-primary: #0EA3FF; --recon-theme-color-secondary: #767676; }</style>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
              .register("/ngsw-worker.js")
              .then(serviceWorker => {
                console.log("Service Worker registered: ", serviceWorker);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error registering the Service Worker: ", error);
              });
    }


  </script>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: You can not run service worker with ng-serve. See :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905172/how-to-run-service-worker-locally-with-angular#:~:text=You%20can't%20serve%20your,locally%20to%20test%20your%20project.

Comment: According to the [Angular 14.2 release notes](https://twitter.com/angular/status/1562938202482102273) (released on 8/25), `ng serve` now has Service Worker support.