# Could not subscribe to notifications Error: Service workers are disabled or not supported by this browser

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I am following the steps that are given in https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/#:~:text=Push%20Notification%20Demo,a%20Notification%20to%20the%20user.

I am trying to get push notification using angular.  But while getting the push notification, I got an error

[image]

I have done the service worker setup.  But don't know why this error is coming

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 - "Service workers are disabled or not supported" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513466/angular-6-service-workers-are-disabled-or-not-supported-error)

Comment: yes working now.. But I am facing another issue now

Comment: I can see the push notification. if I close the push notification without clinking both allow and deny option, the localhost:8080 notification is blocked automatically.  So I couldn't get the push notification again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service workers doesn't work with ng serve. use http-server like below :-

First install a http-server

```
npm i -g http-server
```

Build your project

```
ng build --prod
```

Inside dist run

```
http-server
```

Comment: its working....

Comment: @swetha mark it as answer then.

Comment: I can see the push notification. if I close the push notification without clinking both allow and deny option, the localhost:8080 notification is blocked automatically. So I couldn't get the push notification again